# To use each no. from a string of no's as a unique row value to edit another column in database, do I have to convert string into array first?

Tags: string, jdbc, split, iteration, prepared-statement

I need the breakup of multiple numbers in a string into separate values so I can add these values as row values by iterating and updating a column in a database using jdbc. Do I need to use `string.split()` or is there another way I can iterate without converting into an array?

First I tried iterating the string directly which felt wrong. How do I proceed? Below is part of the program: (the string is called from another servlet. it goes something like (101 201 301 ....) (value of each row). so based on these dynamically received values I need to update respectively in another column with either yes or no(status).

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("Update table_name SET column_name = "+status+ " WHERE column_name2 = (?)");
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
        ps.setString(1, string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute your statement for each number you have in your String.

You can split it into an array and iterate over that array to execute your statement.
And in terms of readability, I prefer to use the for loop this way
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

```
//Assuming string="101 102 103"
String[] arrayString = string.split(" ");

//Here arrayString:
//arrayString[0]= "101"
//arrayString[1]= "102"
//arrayString[2]= "103"

for (String item : arrayString) {
        ps.setString(1, item);
        ps.executeUpdate()          
}
```

There is perhaps other way to do it. But i'm not sure and i wouldn't be precise enough.

Comment: @Koraxoz Thanks . :) But i realized i can use it as a string itself and not needed to  convert into array. this could be used for array i guess. u can check below my ans code if ur interested.

Comment: Great, i saw that possibilty but with 'IN' and now i know it works

Answer (score 1):

So I have used For-each Loop and the output finally came correctly. Basically, we can add all values directly in the form of a string separated by ','. value needed can be added with the help of a place holder.

```
for(String s:boxOption){
        dbSt=dbSt+","+s;
    }
    dbSt=dbSt.substring(5); //to remove the null value.
    System.out.println("string of values selected:"+dbSt);

    ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE table_name SET  column_name =? WHERE column_name2 IN ("+dbSt+")");
    ps.setString(1, status); //status is different for different parameters calling the same method.
    int count=ps.executeUpdate();
```